# Circuit diagram with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits, code-review

Hi I am trying to draw the following circuit:

[image]

using Tikz package in Latex. The following is my code

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{center}
        \ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}
        \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1,transform shape]
            \draw
            %(0,1) node [] {} to [R, l=$R_t$, i>^=$I_t$] (2,1)
            (0,1) to [cspst=$u$] (1.5,1)
            (0,-1) node [] {} -- (6,-1)
            (0,-1) {to [battery, l_=$V_s$] (0,1)}
            (1.5,1) to [L, l=$L_1$, i>^=$I_1$] (1.5,-1)
            (1.5,1) to [C, l=$C_1$, v<={{$V_1$}}] (3.5,1)
            (3.5,1) {to [diode] (3.5,-1)}
            (3.5,1) to [L, l=$L_2$, i>^=$I_2$] (5,1)
            (5,1) to [C, l=$C_2$, v<={{$V_2$}}] (5,-1)
            (6,-1) {to [R, l_=$G$] (6,1)}
            (5,1) -- (6,1);
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Electrical scheme of the zetaconverter.}
    \label{fig:zeta_scheme}
\end{figure}
```

This always results in the following:

[image]

It always invert the sign conversion and the battery too. If I compile in my friend's Mac it becomes normal.

PS: These are my packages and some custom commands:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,calc,positioning,patterns}
\usepackage{balance} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,mindmap,trees}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=2em, minimum width=4em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=blue!20, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\usepackage{blox}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{black!15}
\usepackage{bigints}

\usepackage[american,cute inductors,smartlabels]{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=.375}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/width=.3}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thyristor/height=.8}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thyristor/width=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/height/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/width/.initial=.7}

\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=0.8pt,line cap=round,line join=round]
```

Comment: please merge your code snippet to one small but complete document which we can copy and test. help us to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should because of the difference is version of `circuitikz` used. Quoting from [Circuitikz manual](http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf):

> Since v0.8.2: voltage and current label directions(`v<= / i<=`) do NOT
>   change the orientation of the drawn source shape anymore. Use the
>   ”`invert`” option to rotate the shape of the source. Furthermore, from
>   this version on, the current label(`i=`) at current sources can be used
>   independent of the regular label(`l=`).

Comment: See also https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/101

Comment: This resolved the issue.