# Draw circuit and graph using circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, circuitikz

I am trying to draw these diagrams using CircuitTikz or any alternative would be appreciated as well.

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/filter-fil16.gif

and

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/filter-fil17.gif

Also trying to draw below images...
[image]
[image]

Any way either one of these can drawn? Please advice.

Comment: Check the following question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461247/2288 and the documentation of circuitikz package.

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask for alternatives, there are several, but one is the CTAN package graphics/circuit_macros.  Examples can be seen in examples/examples.pdf of the distribution or at https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/html/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the site! I believe this is a working example on how to use circuitikz.

```
    \documentclass{book}
\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
            (0,0) to (2,0)
            (0,-2) to[I=$i$] (0,0)
            (0,-2) to (2,-2)
            (2,0) to (4,0)
            (2,0) to[capacitor, l=$C$, v=$u_C$, i>^=$i_C$](2,-2)
            (2,-2) to (4,-2)
            (4,0) to (6,0)
            (4,0) to[resistor, l=$R$, v=$u_R$, i>^=$i_R$](4,-2)
            (4,-2) to (6,-2)
            (6,0) to (8,0)
            (6,0) to[inductor, l=$L$,  v=$u_L$, i>^=$i_L$](6,-2)
            (6,-2) to (8,-2)
            (8,0) to [open, v=$U$, *-*](8,-2)
            ;
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

From now on, I believe [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/circuitikz/) might help you finding similar solved problems and here is the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf) of the package CircuitTikZ.